# Devise routes /:param not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise

Using devise 2.1.0
I am trying to send the `new registration` page a `PricingPlan` model.
So in my routes I have:

```
devise_scope :user do
    delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/signup/:plan" => "devise/registrations#new"
  end
```

And I override the devise registration controller. With this in my routes.rb to make it work:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

In my **actual** Registration controller which overrides Devise's controller I have:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  view_paths = "app/views/devise"
  def new
    super
    @plan = PricingPlan.find_by_name(params[:plan])
  end
```

So that the default views still go to devise.... 
In my `new` view for the `registration` controller I call this:

```
<h3>You've chosen the <%= @plan.name %> plan.</h3>
```

And I get this error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Also... in my `PricingPlan` model:

```
class PricingPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
```

And in my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pricing_plan
```

I'm rather new at rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did a `raise` in my registration controller, I realize that when I was hitting /signup/:plan it wasn't hitting the `registrations controller` that I had overode from devises `registration controller`. 
I figure out the reason:
Because I had made my own controller, the scope is no longer devises scope any more... 
So this was **WRONG**:

```
get "/signup/:plan" => "devise/registrations#new"
```

This however is **CORRECT**:

```
get "/signup/:plan" => "registrations#new"
```

So that part of my routes looks like this:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "/signup/:plan" => "registrations#new"
  end
```

Everything else in the code stayed the same. 
Thanks for @gabrielhilal for making me trace out the controller.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason your @plan is empty...

try changing the line below just to make sure that you are finding a plan...

```
@plan = PricingPlan.find_by_id(1)
```

if so, you are probabl trying to find by the wrong argument... do you have a column "plan" in your database?

```
@plan = PricingPlan.find_by_name(params[:______])
```

Comment: You answer helped me go in the right direction and I really appreciate that.